# Construct a triangle given one side and the opposing angle

Tags: geometry

I am given one side of a triangle, and the *opposing* angle. How can I construct the triangle, and / or the solution set?

Comment: you need more data to solve the problem

Comment: From the Law of Cosines we have $c^2=a^2+b^2-2ab\cos (\theta)$, any $a,b$ that satisfy that will yield a triangle with your data ($C, \theta$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Supposing you want to keep the given side fixed, you can draw the given angle at both its extremities, than draw the lines perpendicular to the added rays (the green ones in the picture) through the side extremities. These will meet in the center of the circle on which you can choose the third vertex of your triangle.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

The vertex opposite the given side will lie on a circle for which the given side is a chord.

[image]

By Svjo - Own work, CC BY-SA 4.0, https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=54536891

It's Euclid, Book III, Proposition 31

http://aleph0.clarku.edu/~djoyce/elements/bookIII/propIII31.html

http://jwilson.coe.uga.edu/emt725/AngleSubtendSegment/AngleSubtendSeg.html

Answer (score 0):

Let say , the vertex which angle is given on the x axis and draw to lines which substain that angle and at last draw a line opposite to given angle , which is given